# I want to upload a file and extract it using python tkinter button but getting error in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-button

**I am trying to upload the zip file from one function and extract that file by getting the path in a variable from another function but couldn't get the solution. below is the code of my user-interface and attach is the UI link.**

```
from tkinter import *
from zipfile import ZipFile
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog

def UploadAction():
     input_path = filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[('Zip file', '*.zip')])

# I want to get this (input_path) value and pass to extraction function to extract the file

def extraction():
    john = ZipFile('', 'r')
    john.extractall('C:/Users/anjum/Downloads/New folder')
    john.close()

w2 = Tk()
w2.geometry("1366x768")

uplaod_button = Button(w2, bg="gray", fg="white", text='Upload zip file', width=30, font 
                                                             ("bold", 12), command=UploadAction)
uplaod_button.place(x=600, y=120)

extract = Button(w2, bg="gray", fg="white", text='Extract zip file', font=("bold", 12), width=25, command=extraction)
extract.place(x=620, y=175)

w2.mainloop()
```

[User Interface link][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/57EZ2.png

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include the error.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to declare `input_path` as global variable inside `UploadAction()`, then it can be accessed inside `extraction()`.

Note that it is better to use `askopenfilename()` instead of `askopenfile()`.

```py
input_path = None

def UploadAction():
     global input_path
     input_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('Zip file', '*.zip')])

# I want to get this (input_path) value and pass to extraction function to extract the file

def extraction():
    if input_path:
        john = ZipFile(input_path, 'r')
        john.extractall('C:/Users/anjum/Downloads/New folder')
        john.close()
```

---

Better way is to use class and instance variable:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from zipfile import ZipFile

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('1366x768')

        self.input_path = None

        uplaod_button = tk.Button(self, bg="gray", fg="white", text='Upload zip file',
                                  width=30, font=("bold", 12), command=self.UploadAction)
        uplaod_button.place(x=600, y=120)

        extract = tk.Button(self, bg="gray", fg="white", text='Extract zip file',
                            font=("bold", 12), width=25, command=self.extraction)
        extract.place(x=620, y=175)

    def UploadAction(self):
        self.input_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('Zip file', '*.zip')])

    def extraction(self):
        if self.input_path:
            with ZipFile(self.input_path, 'r') as john:
                john.extractall('C:/Users/anjum/Downloads/New folder')

App().mainloop()
```